# Bind arrow key presses to a certain div no matter what is in focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

I have an html5 video canvas, I would like it to react to all key presses, but especially arrow key presses no matter what is in focus. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Attach the `keypress` event hook to the `document`

Comment: ^^ + don't forget to prevent the default action.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan keypress won't fire when a non-printable character is generated. You need keyup, keydown or input for those. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress

Comment: @ScottMarcus Somewhat browser-dependent ([keypress in FF is triggered by arrows](https://jsfiddle.net/eks68Lxc/), but `input` doesn't trigger event on document in any browser.

Comment: @Teemu FF is known for not following standards when it comes to keyboard input. Which is why the better approach is to use keyup or keydown, which work correctly everywhere.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yes, I agree, the point of my comment was on the use of `oninput` though. Actually the said event bubbles --> you can listen it on document, but only form control elements will trigger it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leverage event bubbling. Key codes for arrow keys are 37-40. Now, when any page element recieves a keydown event, it will bubble to the window object, where it will be handled. At that point, the key will be checked to see if it is an arrow key (you need to fill in the cases as you desire).

```
  window.addEventListener("keydown", function(evt){
     alert(evt.which);
     switch(evt.which){
       case 37:
          alert("Left arrow key pressed!");
          break;
       case 38:
          alert("Up arrow key pressed!");
          break;
       case 39:
          alert("Right arrow key pressed!");
          break;              
       case 40:
          alert("Down arrow key pressed!");
          break; 
       default:
       break;
     }
  });
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/avbto94z/8/ for example with `canvas`. Note that there are several other elements on the page. Click into or use the tab key to move the focus to elements besided the canvas and press keys on the keyboard.

Comment: And then trigger the same event on the div?

Comment: The above code will trigger when ANY page element is in focus and a key is pressed. No need to also hook up the div because events "bubble" from themselves all the way up to the window object.

Comment: Just move the div's event handling code up into this code. No need to have this trigger that.

Comment: I guess I should have made this clearer, but the div itself is an html5 video div with a library responsible for handling it, and so has its own bound events.

Comment: Then yes, just have my code trigger your function. Also, there is no such thing as an HTML5 "video div". Can you please explain?

Comment: Woops, meant canvas.

Comment: And what "library" is responsible for handling it?  I think you mean that canvas has its own API for interacting with it, but canvas is still just an HTML element and, as such, it receives events like any other element. Again, if you move your code (that should run when an arrow key is pressed) into the switch (and no longer have it in the canvas event handler), my solution will work. ALL keydown events that occur against any element (including canvas) will bubble up to the window object and be handled there.